# Android - Fragment in full screen mode with NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-fullscreen

I have an app with a single activity and some fragments. I built it after working through this codelab [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation)( so, it is very similar to that one).
Then I decided to make one of the Fragments appear in fullscreen mode. In this official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive), they only show how it is done for an activity. The `NavigationUI` is not mentioned. Then I have found this SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380587/android-how-to-hide-the-system-ui-properly) but the answers there were also not suitable for my case.

Can someone provide some ideas or hints how this can be done ?
So, when I am navigating from `Fragment_A` to `Fragment_B` and `Fragment_B` should be in full screen mode, how can I implement that ?
For example, I like to study the official Google sample apps but I could not find any sample app with this kind of requirement.

The offical samples like the one [here](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/ImmersiveMode/) also don't provide any useful information.

Comment: Do if  you can make separate activity for it....

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the navigation in your code, for example when you click a button or something like that.

```kotlin
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    val action =
        SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections
            .actionSpecifyAmountFragmentToConfirmationFragment()
    view.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

[Android documentation for Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

And when you navigate to your Fragment, you should do something like that

```kotlin
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

[Android set full screen from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446881/android-set-full-screen-from-fragment)

I think this should work if I am not misunderstanding something...