# When setting background color a white bar remains on top of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio

For my app I want to make the entire screen one color.

The important parts of *activity_main.xml* look like this:

```
...
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
...
```

I hide the System UI using this function:

(credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380780/14384063)

```
private void hideSystemUI(){
    int uiOptions = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

I also found this and added it into *themes.xml*:

```
<!-- Support Display Cutouts -->
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

However the screen is still not totally green:

[image: screen]

It looks like this on the emulator as well as on my phone. What am I missing?
Ideally I'd also be able to use that space for drawing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge). There's a pretty good guide on how to achieve your goal.

Now to answer your question:

The reason why it's not the same color as your screen is that you have enabled the content of the screen to draw below the status bar but it is not actually doing it.

There are two ways to do this.

#### 1. Make the status bar the same color as your background

When the background doesn't change a lot (e.g. is always one color or changes between a couple of solid colors) you can set the status bar color to be the same as your background. This can be done either via your theme or programmatically by calling

```
this.getWindow.setStatusBarColor(yourColor);
```

[Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) to a StackOverflow thread about the topic and some further explanation.

#### 2. Draw your background behind the status bar

Currently your `ConstraintLayout` is sized based on the Window Insets which describe how big elements like the status and navigation bar are. You can draw behind those by adding

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

to your `ConstraintLayout` so it does not confrom to those.

**Warning:**
All children of the view will also not conform to the insets, which is why you'll have to set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

for the immediate child.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response. In my case I fixed the problem by adding `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` to themes.xml.